# Web page URL link with JS onclick relative path?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I have an old web app developed in ASP.Net with the old type code behind style.  I am eventually going to re-do the complete web app in ASP.Net MVC 3 - just starting to complete the first sections and integrate them.  I am having some problems with a menu that appears along the top.  So there is a home button  it looks like the below in code:

```
onclick='document.location.href=\"Home.aspx\"'>
```

However I am getting the url in the new mvc part of web were I have the menu and i try to hit the home icon I get a page not found:

/MyWeb.Web.App/mvc/Controller/Home.aspx

The actual home aspx page exists in the location \MyWeb.Web.App\mvc\Home.aspx

I am currently stumped as to what I can edit in the JS href to get it to point to this location so the icons will work in the existing implementation and the new MVC one.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use urls helpers. For example if you are using Razor and this code is inside an MVC view:

```
onclick='document.location.href="@Url.Content("~/mvc/home.aspx")"'>
```

or if you are using the WebForms view engine:

```
onclick='document.location.href="<%= Url.Content("~/mvc/home.aspx") %>"'>
```

---

UPDATE:

If this is in a separate javascript file then you could declare a global variable inside your Razor view that will point to the base url:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var baseUrl = '@Url.Content("~/mvc")';
</script>
```

and then inside your javascript file:

```
onclick='document.location.href=\"" + baseUrl + "/home.aspx\"'
```

There are of course much better ways to achieve that but since you haven't provided enough details about your scenario it's difficult to suggest what might be best. For example you could use HTML5 `data-*` attributes in your DOM or some other elements to generate properly this url and access it in your javascript file.

Comment: Hi Darin - thanks for prompt reply - I am using Razor but the menu code is all done in a seperate JS file.  So I just have an include file on my main _Layout.cshtml Razor page that includes this JS file for every Razor page which then creates the menu.

Comment: Then you could use a global variable to point to the root of your folder and then use this variable in your javascript file.